# Issue with returning a Directory Enumerator from NSFileManager using enumeratorAtUrl in Swift

Tags: swift

I am attempting to return a NSDirectoryEnumerator object from the NSFileManager method enumeratorAtUrl. This results in a **compiler error**:
 `Cannot convert the expressions type 'NSDirectoryEnumerator!' to type 'NSDirectoryEnumeratorOptions'`

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/")
var keys:Array<AnyObject> = [NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
var manager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url,includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: 0, errorHandler: nil)
```

This works in Obj-C but not Swift.. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: Note: returning an NSDirectoryEnumerator via the enumeratorAtPath method still functions normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(), errorHandler: nil)
```

Or in short, pass in `NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions()` instead of "`0`".

"0" is not really a member of the enumeration it is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.1+**

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/")
let keys: [URLResourceKey] = [.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey]
let manager = FileManager.default
let options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants]
let enumerator = manager.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: options, errorHandler: nil)
```

**Swift 2.0**

No options:

```
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: [], errorHandler: nil)
```

One option:

```
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles, errorHandler: nil)
```

Multiple options:

```
let options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.SkipsHiddenFiles, .SkipsPackageDescendants]
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: options, errorHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kendall's answer is perfect for most cases, but if you need to adjust the behavior of the enumerator, here are some examples.

Configure the enumerator to skip hidden files:

```
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles, errorHandler: nil)
```

If you need to set multiple options, you "or" them together:

```
let options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions = .SkipsHiddenFiles | .SkipsPackageDescendants
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: options, errorHandler: nil)
```