# changing code from Swift 1 to 2, Error: Type 'NSDirectoryEnumeration Options' does not conform to Protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift2

changing code from Swift 1 to 2,

> Error: Type 'NSDirectoryEnumeration Options' does not conform to Protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible' on line 6 below:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)

          if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {

          let urls = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil 
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

No options

```
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: [], errorHandler: nil)
```

Only one option

```
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles, errorHandler: nil)
```

Multiple options

```
let options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.SkipsHiddenFiles, .SkipsPackageDescendants]
let enumerator = manager.enumeratorAtURL(url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: options, errorHandler: nil)
```

Resource (answered by @Marc):
[Issue with returning a Directory Enumerator from NSFileManager using enumeratorAtUrl in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152305/issue-with-returning-a-directory-enumerator-from-nsfilemanager-using-enumeratora)